# Scan QR Code value into an input field after successful scan

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the scanner I am using...

https://github.com/takanori-matsushita/webcodecamjs

It's working 100%. But I need to add some custom extra's.

When the QR Code is scanned it outputs my result into this paragraph tag.

```
<p id="scanned-QR"> The scanned code text value is printed out here </p>
```

However I need it to be an input field so I can use it's value in a url.

How can I set an input field equal to the value submitted to the Paragraph tag?

I have tried these methods and they failed :

Method 1

```
<input id="scanned-QR"> The scanned code text value is printed out here </input>
```

Method 2

```
<p id="scanned-QR" onchange="update"></p>
 <input id="code_id_value" type="text" name="" value="">
<br>

<script>
 function update(){
  var code_id_value = document.getElementById("scanned-QR").innertext;
  document.getElementById("code_id_value").value = code_id_value;
 }
</script>
```

Comment: If you look into the example in the website you enclosed, you can get the decode value through init with this arg:             var arg = {
                resultFunction: function(result) {
                    /*
                        result.format: code format,
                        result.code: decoded string,
                        result.imgData: decoded image data
                    */


                }
            };

Comment: You could just use `.innerHTML` to get or set the text of DOM Elements that are not `<input />`s. There's no real reason to put the text into an input, since you have the info already, unless you're trying to do old school form submission. I recommend AJAX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key that you're missing is that the `T` in `.innertext` needs to be capitalised (as **[`.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText)**).

In addition to this, using inline event handlers is bad practice, and you should consider using [**`.addEventListener()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of **[`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange)**.

This can be seen working in the following:

```js
document.getElementById("scanned-QR").addEventListener("click", update);

function update() {
  var code_id_value = document.getElementById("scanned-QR").innerText;
  document.getElementById("code_id_value").value = code_id_value;
}

// Demo
update();
```

```html
<p id="scanned-QR">Text</p>
<input id="code_id_value" type="text" name="" value="">
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I get the Logic. But for some reason it's not picking up the change and its not running the function?

Comment: Might you know why?

Comment: It would depend on how you're actually *triggering* the change. But assuming you are triggering the element to change (and you can see it changing), then the input will be populated as well... **unless** the `<p>` element is dynamically-generated. In which case, you'll have to make use of [**event delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Answer (score 0):

So this is the solution I came up with.

Here's my paragraph and input function

```
<p id="scanned-QR" onchange="update">SCAN.BZ</p>
<input id="code_id_value" type="text" name="" value="">
```

Here's my function. WITH a interval for every millisecond or faster "I think it's every millisecond".

It runs smoothly and doesn't lag. and the result is practically immediate.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 setInterval(update,1);
   function update() {
      var code_id_value = document.getElementById("scanned-QR").innerHTML;
      document.getElementById("code_id_value").value = code_id_value;
    }
    update();
</script>
```

Thanks for the help "Obsidian Age" Really appreciate it. :)

Comment: You should probably cancel that timer unless you're navigating away immediately.

Comment: I am navigating away Immediately :) Thanks